# Netbeans: Sass "Compile Sass Files on Save" Checkbox missing

Tags: netbeans, sass

I run Netbeans 8.0.2 on Windows.

The checkbox "Compile Sass Files On Save" was there before I installed Sass.
[image: checkbox "Compile Sass Files On Save"]

I installed Sass, configured the path in Netbeans.
`C:\Ruby193\bin\sass.bat`

Now this dialog is missing.

[image]

Does anybody knows how to get it back?
Or why it's gone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already checked it, it won't be displayed anymore for the given project. You need to right click on your project, select Properties and then category CSS Preprocessors. There you  can configure Sass/Less compilers.